# on_raw_reaction_remove not working when paired with _add

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am working on a Discord bot (thanks to some of the users here who provided previous answers and helped me get it working at all in the past) and having some trouble getting it to remove roles after adding them. I have included my code below....

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import os
import datetime
import asyncio
from typing import Self
import requests as rq
import discord
import discord.ext
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
intents = discord.Intents.all()bot = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", intents=intents)
self = bot
class Embed(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id) # Get guild
    member = get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # Get the member out of the guild
    # The channel ID should be an integer:
    if payload.channel_id == 1080162990181064714: # Only channel where it will work
        if str(payload.emoji) == "❌": # Your emoji
            role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, id=1080163217877254174) # Role ID
        else:
            role = get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji)
        if role is not None: # If role exists
            await payload.member.add_roles(role)
            print(f"Added {role}")

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
    if payload.channel_id == 1080162990181064714:
        if str(payload.emoji) == "❌":
                role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, id=1080163217877254174)
        else:
            role = get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji)
        if role is not None:
            await payload.member.remove_roles(role)
            print(f"Removed {role}")


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

This is the error its throwing me in the terminal...

```
2023-02-28 12:06:37 ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_remove
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "e:\Turlington - Test\bot.py", line 155, in on_raw_reaction_remove
    role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, id=1080163217877254174)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

Answer (score 0):

`payload.member` seems to be `None`. You can try getting the member yourself:

`member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)`

[EDIT]

Seems like you're already doing it. Actually, you already have guild object, so just replace

`role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, id=1080163217877254174)`

with

`role = get(guild.roles, id=1080163217877254174)`

Or even better (as you have the id)

`role = guild.get_role(1080163217877254174)`

Comment: Hey! So I'm a bit confused what you mean. I already have that at the top of the on_raw_reaction_removed, right under it. Is that not correct?

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)

Comment: Oh, sorry! I wasn't careful enough. Updated the answer.

Comment: So I went ahead and made that change in the remove role command section, but its still giving me the same error message. 

Its saying "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'

Is "await payload.member.remove_roles(role)" not correct for that line?

Comment: Use member instead of payload.member, same as in the previous situation